# Grep lines not matching a character class

Tags: class, grep, posix

I am trying to write a simple grep script that will search documents for lines containing no whitespace or tabs, but I am having difficulty. I dont want it to use options for grep I just want to do it with the classes themselves, but I am unsure how to do this.

The last attempt I made that failed was grep '[^[:blank:]*]

Answer (score 0):

you want /^[^[:blank:]]*$/

use this to test: http://rubular.com/

try putting "^[^[:blank:]]*$" under "Your regular expression:"

and start typing in the text area below.

here's an example: http://rubular.com/r/WfiXhl3jPV